# Mac OSX - AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region'

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

Walking through matplotlib's animation example on my Mac OSX machine - http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html - I am getting this error:-

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 248, in _blit_clear
    a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region'
```

Does anyone who has encountered this before know how to resolve this issue?

Looks like it's a known (and unresolved at this time of writing) issue - https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/531

Comment: Confirmed. Just tried it and had the same error continuously.

Answer (score 47):

Just set

```
blit=False
```

when [animation.FuncAnimation()](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) is called and it will work.

For instance ([from double_pendulum_animated](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html)):

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, len(y)), interval=25, blit=False, init_func=init)
```

Comment: Hey @jw1123, how did you know to set blit=False?  This worked for me, just trying to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: From http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/,
blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed. And the default OS X back-end doesn't currently support this (which also explains Beau's answer).

Comment: @ingrid I think I figured it out by trial and error. I'm sorry that I can't share more insight...

Answer (score 25):

You can avoid the problem by switching to a different backend:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Comment: Note that this requires that Tk must be installed (not necessarily satisfied), and that this must become before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: It depends how you installed your python installation, with brew there can be some issues (but can be resolved).

Answer (score 5):

As noted at https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2012-September/023664.html use:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

#just *before*

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

This has worked for me with Tkinter installed using the ActiveState Tkinter installation on OSX 10.11.6, Python 2.71 
The basic animation example is still a little noisy until blt=False in the line_ani code here:

```
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
interval=50, blit=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a known (and unresolved at this time of writing) issue - https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/531