# How to interactively find and annotate local max (peaks) in matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, data-analysis

I'm trying to analyze some spectra for finding spectroscopic peaks, I've writen this simple code to find the max Y value (the peak) between two X data by clicking before and after the peak that I want to find. This works and I can get the coordinate of the peak but I would like to automatically annotate the peak found.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y=[1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,Y,label="prova") #plot the function
#plt.legend(loc=1, ncol=1, shadow=True)
plt.xlim(min(X) * 0.9, max(X) * 1.1)
plt.ylim(min(Y) * 0.9, max(Y) * 1.1)
plt.ylabel(r'Y axis')
plt.xlabel(r'X axis')
Diz=dict(zip(X,Y)) #create a dictionary that associate X with Y
Interval=[] #interval where the user search for peaks
PeaksList=[] #list of peaks found
def onclick(event):
    print 'First limit at =%f'%(event.xdata)
    Interval.append(event.xdata)
    if len(Interval)%2==0:
        a=Interval[-2]       
        b=Interval[-1]    
        if b<a: #if the user select first the highest value these statements filp it!
            A=b
            B=a
        else:
            A=a
            B=b
      #find the max Y value: the peak!
        peakY=0 #max Y value
        piccoX=0 #value of the X associate to the peak
        for i in [ j for j in X if A<j<B] :
            if Diz[i]>peakY:
                peakY=Diz[i]
                piccoX=i
        print "Interval: %f - %f  Peak at: %f " %(a,b,piccoX)
        PeaksList.append([piccoX,peakY])
        ax.annotate("picco", xy=(piccoX,peakY),  xycoords='data',
                xytext=(-50, 30), textcoords='offset points',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->")
                )      


plt.show()         
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

This is what I would like to have after the second click:
[image]

Comment: do you want the find and annotate all maxima?

Comment: @Jakob I would like to annotate the peak I've found clicking before and after it how I've written in the question. Try the code for understand! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redraw the figure - simply by adding a `plt.draw` to the onclick method.
Moreover you have to connect the event before you show the figure.
Of course, here your annotation text is 'picco' not '5'.

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y=[1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,Y,label="prova") #plot the function
#plt.legend(loc=1, ncol=1, shadow=True)
plt.xlim(min(X) * 0.9, max(X) * 1.1)
plt.ylim(min(Y) * 0.9, max(Y) * 1.1)
plt.ylabel(r'Y axis')
plt.xlabel(r'X axis')
Diz=dict(zip(X,Y)) #create a dictionary that associate X with Y
Interval=[] #interval where the user search for peaks
PeaksList=[] #list of peaks found
def onclick(event):
    print 'First limit at =%f'%(event.xdata)
    Interval.append(event.xdata)
    if len(Interval)%2==0:
        a=Interval[-2]       
        b=Interval[-1]    
        if b<a: #if the user select first the highest value these statements filp it!
            A=b
            B=a
        else:
            A=a
            B=b
      #find the max Y value: the peak!
        peakY=0 #max Y value
        piccoX=0 #value of the X associate to the peak
        for i in [ j for j in X if A<j<B] :
            if Diz[i]>peakY:
                peakY=Diz[i]
                piccoX=i
        print "Interval: %f - %f  Peak at: %f " %(a,b,piccoX)
        PeaksList.append([piccoX,peakY])
        ax.annotate("picco", xy=(piccoX,peakY),  xycoords='data',
                xytext=(-50, 30), textcoords='offset points',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->")
                )
        plt.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Maybe visually more appealing (using the spanselector):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y=[1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,Y,label="prova") #plot the function
#plt.legend(loc=1, ncol=1, shadow=True)
plt.xlim(min(X) * 0.9, max(X) * 1.1)
plt.ylim(min(Y) * 0.9, max(Y) * 1.1)
plt.ylabel(r'Y axis')
plt.xlabel(r'X axis')
Diz=dict(zip(X,Y)) #create a dictionary that associate X with Y
Interval=[] #interval where the user search for peaks
PeaksList=[] #list of peaks found
def onclick(xmin, xmax):
    print 'Interval: {0} - {1}'.format(xmin,xmax)
    peakY=0 #max Y value
    piccoX=0 #value of the X associate to the peak
    for i in [ j for j in X if xmin<j<xmax] :
        if Diz[i]>peakY:
            peakY=Diz[i]
            piccoX=i
    print "Peak at: %f " % piccoX
    PeaksList.append([piccoX,peakY])
    ax.annotate("picco", xy=(piccoX,peakY),  xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-50, 30), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
    plt.draw()

span = SpanSelector(ax, onclick, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                    rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='blue') )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jakob, I will wait a little bit then I will acepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've added a SpanSelector version to my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works but I've the following ERROR: `AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'copy_from_bbox'` I don't see the rectangle in my OSX.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have OSX so I did not test this with different backends. There is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13216520/2870069 dealing with exactly this issue. Maybe the answers can help you.

Comment: Ok as you prefer! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Is this possible also in an IPython / Jupyter notebook? The cursor seems to not work in such web notebook. Thanks!

Comment: @Ralf Yes, it should work in all interactive backends including the notebook (nbagg) backend. Simple add the following line at the beginning `%matplotlib notebook`. Note, the _inline_ backend is not interactive, and thus, won't work here.

Comment: @Jakob: Amazing job! Thanks! With %matplotlib notebook, it works well...