# How do I get the graph to open a new window when run?

Tags: python, json, matplotlib

I would like for the resulting graph to be in a new window. I know the phrase, `%matplotlib inline` puts the graph in the console, but if I remove it it gives me the error

> FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'get_renderer.

Is there a way I can go around this?

```
import re
import ftplib
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import numpy as np
import pylab
import re
import sunpy.time
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import *
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from adjustText import adjust_text
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
import sys

info = []
parsedFilename = []
dateAndTime = []
xcen = []
ycen = []
sciObj = []
xfov = []
yfov = []
matchingAR = []

def getNumberOfEntries(theJSON):
    return len(dateAndTime)   

def getInfo(counter, theJSON):
    cont = True
    while cont:
        try:
            dateAndTime.append(theJSON["Events"][counter]["date"])
            xcen.append(float("%.2f" % theJSON["Events"][counter]["xCen"]))
            ycen.append(float("%.2f" % theJSON["Events"][counter]["yCen"]))
            xfov.append(float("%.2f" % theJSON["Events"][counter]["raster_fovx"]))
            yfov.append(float("%.2f" % theJSON["Events"][counter]["raster_fovy"]))
            sciObj.append(theJSON["Events"][counter]["sciObjectives"])
            counter = counter + 1
            getInfo(counter, theJSON)
        except IndexError:
            cont = False
        break

def setXMax(theJSON):      
    xmax = xcen[0]
    for i in range (0, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        if xcen[i] > xmax:
            xmax = xcen[i]
    return round(xmax + 150,-1)

def setXMin(theJSON):
    xmin = xcen[0]
    for i in range (0, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        if xcen[i] < xmin:
            xmin = xcen[i]
    return round(xmin - 150, -1)

def setYMax(theJSON):      
    ymax = ycen[0]
    for i in range (0, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        if ycen[i] > ymax:
            ymax = ycen[i]
    return round(ymax + 150, -1)

def setYMin(theJSON):
    ymin = ycen[0]
    for i in range (0, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        if ycen[i] < ymin:
            ymin = ycen[i]
    return round(ymin - 150, -1)         

# def sort():
#     for i in range(len(dateAndTime)):
#         for j in range(len(xcen)-1, i, -1):
#             if ( xcen[j] < xcen[j-1]):
#                 temp1 = dateAndTime[j]
#                 dateAndTime[j] = dateAndTime[j-1]
#                 dateAndTime[j-1] = temp1

#                 temp2 = xcen[j]
#                 xcen[j] = xcen[j-1]
#                 xcen[j-1] = temp2

#                 temp3 = ycen[j]
#                 ycen[j] = ycen[j-1]
#                 ycen[j-1] = temp3

#                 temp4 = xfov[j]
#                 xfov[j] = xcen[j-1]
#                 xfov[j-1]=temp4

#                 temp5 = yfov[j]
#                 yfov[j] = ycen[j-1]
#                 yfov[j-1]=temp5

#                 temp6 = sciObj[j]
#                 sciObj[j] = sciObj[j-1]
#                 sciObj[j-1] = temp6

def sort():
    for i in range(len(dateAndTime)):
        for j in range(len(dateAndTime)-1, i, -1):
            if ( dateAndTime[j] < dateAndTime[j-1]):

                temp1 = dateAndTime[j]
                dateAndTime[j] = dateAndTime[j-1]
                dateAndTime[j-1] = temp1

                temp2 = xcen[j]
                xcen[j] = xcen[j-1]
                xcen[j-1] = temp2

                temp3 = ycen[j]
                ycen[j] = ycen[j-1]
                ycen[j-1] = temp3

                temp4 = xfov[j]
                xfov[j] = xcen[j-1]
                xfov[j-1]=temp4

                temp5 = yfov[j]
                yfov[j] = ycen[j-1]
                yfov[j-1]=temp5

                temp6 = sciObj[j]
                sciObj[j] = sciObj[j-1]
                sciObj[j-1] = temp6


def createAnnotations(theJSON):
    annotations = []
    for i in range(getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        annotations.append('(' + str(xcen[i])+ ', '+ str(ycen[i]) + ')')

    return annotations

def fixAnnotations(annotations):
    texts = []
    for xt, yt, s in zip(xcen, ycen, annotations):
        texts.append(plt.text(xt, yt, s))
    return texts

def plot(theJSON):   
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 20))
    circle = Circle((0, 0), 980, facecolor='none', edgecolor=(0, 0.8, 0.8), linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(circle)

    plt.plot(xcen, ycen, color="red") 
    plt.plot(xcen, ycen, 'ro', color = 'blue')

    plt.xlim([setXMin(theJSON), setXMax(theJSON)])
    plt.ylim([setYMin(theJSON), setYMax(theJSON)])

    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(setXMin(theJSON), setXMax(theJSON), 50))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(setYMin(theJSON), setYMax(theJSON), 50))


    for i in range(getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        if xfov[i] != 0:
            xStart = xcen[i] - xfov[i]/20
            yStart = ycen[i] - yfov[i]/20
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((xStart, yStart), xfov[i]/10, yfov[i]/10, facecolor='none'))

    texts = fixAnnotations(createAnnotations(theJSON))

    f = interpolate.interp1d(xcen, ycen)
    x = np.linspace(min(xcen), max(ycen), 1000)
    y = f(x)
    adjust_text(texts, x, y, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=2.0), autoalign='y', only_move={'points':'y', 'text':'y'}, expand_points=(1.2, 1.4), force_points=0.40)

    plt.grid()

    plt.show()
    main(False)

def searchOnceMore(searchAgain):
    if searchAgain == True:
        noaaNmbr = input('Enter desired active region: ')
        return noaaNmbr
    else:
        continueSearch = input('Would you like to search again?(yes/no)')
        if continueSearch == 'yes':
            noaaNmbr = input('Enter desired active region:')
            return noaaNmbr
        elif continueSearch == 'no':
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print('please enter "yes" or "no"')
            searchOnceMore(False)

def main(searchAgain):
    noaaNmbr = searchOnceMore(searchAgain)
    urlData = "http://www.lmsal.com/hek/hcr?cmd=search-events3&outputformat=json&instrument=IRIS&noaanum="+ noaaNmbr +"&hasData=true"
    webUrl = urlopen(urlData)
    counter = 0
    if (webUrl.getcode()==200):                
        data = webUrl.read().decode('utf-8')
        theJSON = json.loads(data)
        getInfo(counter, theJSON)
    else:
        print ("You done messed up!!!")

    sort()

    for i in range (getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
        print(dateAndTime[i])
        print("(", xcen[i], ", ", ycen[i], ")")
        print(sciObj[i])
        print(' ')

    if getNumberOfEntries(theJSON) != 0:
        plot(theJSON)
    else:
        print('No observations for active region ' + noaaNmbr)
        main()

main(True)
```

Comment: Is all that code really necessary for the question to be answered?

Comment: Have you gone through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216520/mac-osx-attributeerror-figurecanvasmac-object-has-no-attribute-restore-reg) SO post?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifiable example showing the problem.  People aren't going to wade through 225 lines of code to find the problem.

Comment: Ok sorry about that I will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also used python and would suggest using John Zelle's graphic file. http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/
It's much more easier to understand and use in my opinion.

To open a new graph window:

```
Win1 = GraphWin("Graph Window 1", 100,100)

win2 = GraphWin("Graph Window 2", 100,150)
```

You can also open the python file to understand how it works. It might help understanding how to open a graph window your way. I only know how to open a new Graph Window through this file sorry, I hope it helps anyway!