# AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region' with matplotlib animation example on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, animation, matplotlib

Using the example code from matplotlib site:

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region'
```

spammed in the output as the animation loops. The animation itself doens't display, and just shows:

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80ZhO.png)

This code works fine on my windows PC, and the other [post I could find on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216520/mac-osx-attributeerror-figurecanvasmac-object-has-no-attribute-restore-reg) recommends you set:

```
blit=False
```

to fix. I still get the same error, so not sure whether anyone knows how I can fix this. The code I'm running is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line,

fig1 = plt.figure()

data = np.random.rand(2, 25)
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.title('test')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
    interval=50, blit=True)
#line_ani.save('lines.mp4')

fig2 = plt.figure()

x = np.arange(-9, 10)
y = np.arange(-9, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
base = np.hypot(x, y)
ims = []
for add in np.arange(15):
    ims.append((plt.pcolor(x, y, base + add, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 30)),))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,
    blit=True)
#im_ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: When I set `blit=False` the example works fine on my Mac (OS-X 10.11.5, matplotlib 1.5.0). Did you set both the `blit` keywords to False?

Answer (score 0):

Must set `blit=False` in both `FuncAnimation()` and `ArtistAnimation()` and the code seems to work fine. Using python 3.4 and py34-matplotlib 1.5.2 from MacPorts.