# Python, conflict between matplotlib's animation and dashed lines

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am using python and matplotlib to create a simple animation.
My code is the following:

```
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import animation as animation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def w(q): return np.exp(-q**2)

support_q = np.linspace(-10,10,200)
support_q1 = np.linspace(-10,10,30)

list_w = [[w(q-q1) for q in support_q] for q1 in support_q1]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlabel='q', ylabel='w(q-q\')')
line_w, = ax.plot(support_q, list_w[0])
plt.axhline(dashes=[10], zorder=0)
ax.xaxis.major.locator.set_params(nbins=12)
ax.yaxis.major.locator.set_params(nbins=5)


def animate(i):
    line_w.set_ydata(list_w[i])
    return line_w,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(support_q1), interval=10, blit=False)
#anim.save('animation.mp4')
plt.show()
```

The code runs smoothly and produces the animation I want. However, if I include a saving command `anim.save('animation.mp4')` just before showing the animation, I get the following error code:

```
File "/Users/usr1/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 166, in draw_path
self._renderer.draw_path(gc, path, transform, rgbFace)
ValueError: dashes sequence must have an even number of elements
```

I am using Mac OS X. The exact same error occurs is replicated if instead of saving the animation I try to change the backend to TkAgg (using `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`). Changing the backend is a workaround for Mac users who want to use the `blit=True` option in `FuncAnimation` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216520/mac-osx-attributeerror-figurecanvasmac-object-has-no-attribute-restore-reg)) but I am not able to implement it because of this error.

I worked out that the issue originates from having a dashed axis added to the plot. That is, if I remove the line

```
plt.axhline(color='k', dashes=[10], zorder=0)
```

both problems vanish and there is no ValueError.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening? Is the animation module incapable of handling dashed lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TkAgg and Qt4Agg I can reproduce the error even without using an animation at all. The reason is indeed the line

```
plt.axhline(dashes=[10])
```

From [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_dashes) we learn that `dashes`

> set[s] the dash sequence, sequence of dashes with on off ink in points. If seq is empty or if seq = (None, None), the linestyle will be set to solid.

Now, it's clear that `[10]` is not a sequence of "on off",  but only "on". A valid sequence would contain at least two numbers.

So, indeed, if we use a valid sequence, e.g.

```
plt.axhline(dashes=[10,3])
```

everything runs without problem.